# voice matching application

Tags: asp.net

Person A records his voice.

Person B will speak same word... we need to match the voice in voice graph... is there any chart to display the voice frequency

Comment: Ok, so what are you having a problem with? No one is going to write something for you to do this.

Comment: And what does this have to do with ASP.NET?

Comment: is there any chart that can be used with voice that can display voice graph...

Answer (score 1):

Try this program: Voice converter, it has a Voice Matching feature
http://www.voiceconverter.net